# Why does Django/console give me an error of missing value for stripe.confirmCardPayment intent secret, saying it should be a client secret string?

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I'm trying to learn this tutorial, the custom payment flow last bit to integrate stripe with Django

https://justdjango.com/blog/django-stripe-payments-tutorial

in my views.py, I have these views

```
class StripeIntentView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            req_json = json.loads(request.body)
            customer = stripe.Customer.create(email=req_json['email'])
            price = Price.objects.get(id=self.kwargs["pk"])
            intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
                amount=price.price,
                currency='usd',
                customer=customer['id'],
                metadata={
                    "price_id": price.id
                }
            )
            return JsonResponse({
                'clientSecret': intent['client_secret']
            })
        
        except Exception as e:
            return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)})

class CustomPaymentView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "custom_payment.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        product = Product.objects.get(name="Test Product")
        prices = Price.objects.filter(product=product)
        context = super(CustomPaymentView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            "product": product,
            "prices": prices,
            "STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY": settings.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY
        })
        return context
```

and in my urls I have

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from products.views import stripe_webhook
from products.views import StripeIntentView, CustomPaymentView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('create-payment-intent/<pk>/', StripeIntentView.as_view(), name='create-payment-intent'),
    path('custom-payment/', CustomPaymentView.as_view(), name='custom-payment')
```

and in my custom_payment.html I have

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Custom payment</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?version=3.52.1&features=fetch"></script>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'products/global.css' %}">
</head>
    
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="product">
            <div class="description">
                <h3>{{ product.name }}</h3>
                <hr />
                <select id='prices'>
                    {% for price in prices %}
                    <option value="{{ price.id }}">${{ price.get_display_price }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>

            <form id="payment-form">{% csrf_token %}
                <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email address" />
                <div id="card-element">
                    <!--Stripe.js injects the Card Element-->
                </div>
                <button id="submit">
                    <div class="spinner hidden" id="spinner"></div>
                    <span id="button-text">Pay</span>
                </button>
                <p id="card-error" role="alert"></p>
                <p class="result-message hidden">
                    Payment succeeded, see the result in your
                    <a href="https://dashboard.stripe.com" target="_blank">Stripe dashboard.</a> Refresh the page to
                    pay again.
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script>
var csrftoken = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;
var stripe = Stripe("{{ STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY }}");
document.querySelector("button").disabled = true;
var elements = stripe.elements();
var style = {
  base: {
    color: "#32325d",
    fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif',
    fontSmoothing: "antialiased",
    fontSize: "16px",
    "::placeholder": {
      color: "#32325d"
    }
  },
  invalid: {
    fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif',
    color: "#fa755a",
    iconColor: "#fa755a"
  }
};
var card = elements.create("card", { style: style });
// Stripe injects an iframe into the DOM
card.mount("#card-element");
card.on("change", function (event) {
  // Disable the Pay button if there are no card details in the Element
  document.querySelector("button").disabled = event.empty;
  document.querySelector("#card-error").textContent = event.error ? event.error.message : "";
});
var form = document.getElementById("payment-form");
form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var selectedPrice = document.getElementById("prices").value
  // Complete payment when the submit button is clicked
  fetch(`/create-payment-intent/${selectedPrice}/`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      email: document.getElementById('email').value
    })
  })
    .then(function(result) {
      return result.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      payWithCard(stripe, card, data.clientSecret);
    });
});

// Calls stripe.confirmCardPayment
// If the card requires authentication Stripe shows a pop-up modal to
// prompt the user to enter authentication details without leaving your page.
var payWithCard = function(stripe, card, clientSecret) {
  loading(true);
  stripe
    .confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
      payment_method: {
        card: card
      }
    })
    .then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Show error to your customer
        showError(result.error.message);
      } else {
        // The payment succeeded!
        orderComplete(result.paymentIntent.id);
      }
    });
};
/* ------- UI helpers ------- */
// Shows a success message when the payment is complete
var orderComplete = function(paymentIntentId) {
  loading(false);
  document
    .querySelector(".result-message a")
    .setAttribute(
      "href",
      "https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/payments/" + paymentIntentId
    );
  document.querySelector(".result-message").classList.remove("hidden");
  document.querySelector("button").disabled = true;
};
// Show the customer the error from Stripe if their card fails to charge
var showError = function(errorMsgText) {
  loading(false);
  var errorMsg = document.querySelector("#card-error");
  errorMsg.textContent = errorMsgText;
  setTimeout(function() {
    errorMsg.textContent = "";
  }, 4000);
};
// Show a spinner on payment submission
var loading = function(isLoading) {
  if (isLoading) {
    // Disable the button and show a spinner
    document.querySelector("button").disabled = true;
    document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.remove("hidden");
    document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.add("hidden");
  } else {
    document.querySelector("button").disabled = false;
    document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.add("hidden");
    document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.remove("hidden");
  }
};

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The tutorial was missing a csrf token so I added that and the card element loaded up, and also I had to add an id of prices to the select

Then I got this error

```
(index):1 Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: Missing value for stripe.confirmCardPayment intent secret: value should be a client_secret string.
    at X ((index):1)
    at Q ((index):1)
    at uo ((index):1)
    at (index):1
    at (index):1
    at e.<anonymous> ((index):1)
    at e.confirmCardPayment ((index):1)
    at payWithCard ((index):104)
    at (index):94
```

Can anyone help me with this ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would suggest adding an additional line to check what is the value of data (and data.clientSecret). It looks like `clientSecret` may not have a value, or may not be a string.

```
.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  payWithCard(stripe, card, data.clientSecret);
});
```

You would then need to trace why `clientSecret` does not have the expected value.

Comment: Thanks, I console logged the data and it said I was missing the stripe api key. 
added that in and it worked! Thanks